# How to change default Eclipse WTP "Web Resources" dynamic folder

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-wtp

I need to change the default Eclipse WTP "Web Resources" dynamic folder. Currently it points to WebContent, and I need to point to src\main\webapp.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found the solution:
Under .settings folder in your project's folder, there is a file named "org.eclipse.wst.common.component", inside it change the line `<wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/WebContent"/>` with `<wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/src/main/webapp"/>`.

That's all!

Comment: I realize that you can add as many entries with deploy-path="/" as you want to indicate the whole web content folder.

Comment: Rather than modifying the `.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component` file directly, you can manage the `deploy-path` entries under _Properties_ > _Deployment Assembly_.

Comment: @penfold The problem is that in previous versions of Eclipse, I swear that it weren't possible... but I'm not sure 100%.

Answer (score 7):

Give Preference to eclipse GUI!

if don't appear to you see this

[Unable to find Deployment assembly Eclipse Juno](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13971331/unable-to-find-deployment-assembly-eclipse-juno)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I prefer the following solution, as the configuration is then saved in the `.project` file and also all files are kept visible in the Eclipse Project Explorer.

Create a Linked Folder called `WebContent` pointing to `/src/main/webapp`:

Right click project > New > Folder. Folder name: `WebContent`. Advanced > Link to alternate location (Linked Folder): `PROJECT_LOC/src/main/webapp`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Disable "Dynamic Web Module" project nature, click "Apply" button
2. Enable previous option checkbox, notice "Feather configuration available..." at the bottom.
3. Click "Feather configuration available..." link and change directory
4. Click "Apply" button

Answer (score 0):

Or you may even do a simple rename of WebContent directory. Eclipse will update the above mention settings files

Comment: But, what if you want to use a existing directory like src/main/webapp?

Comment: Renaming the directory inside Eclipse? I tried that outside Eclipse but it didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that the jsp located in resources/templates were not found

The solution has been to change

```
<wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src/main/resources"/>
```

by the following

```
<wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/src/main/resources"/>
```

That is, modifying the file

```
.settings\org.eclipse.wst.common.component
```