# Unable to find Deployment assembly Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

I am trying to set up "Web Deployment Assembly in project properties".

I want to add "jtds-1.3.0.jar" to the project. But I cannot find "Deployment Assembly" option under properties of the project.

Please suggest me how to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That means that either:

- Your Eclipse distribution doesn't contain WTP (which Eclipse distribution did you download? make sure you downloaded a distribution that includes WTP, such as "Eclipse for JavaEE developers").
- Your project isn't defined as a Dynamic Web Project. Check the Project Facets; if you don't see "Dynamic Web Module" there, then that would explain your problem. You will most likely have to recreate your project.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That project is a Maven project. I added it as existing Maven project. Can you tell if I can convert this as Dynamic web project

Comment: I figured as much. As far as I know, there is no "clean" way of doing it other than recreating the project as a Dynamic Web Project, and *then* right-clicking it, *Configure* -> *Convert to Maven Project*. The designation of a project as a "Dynamic Web Project" involves certain entries in the project's metafiles; so, you could take the risk and simply modify those meta-files by yourself. If you choose to do so, you'll fare better if you create a sample Dynamic Web Project, compare the meta-files of the two projects and copy relevant meta-files/lines from the sample project into yours.

Comment: If you do so, however, make sure that you turn off automatic building before, and re-enable it after. The last thing you want is for Eclipse to try building a project while you're manually manipulating its meta-files.