# Execute targets in a sequence

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have a mvn script that compiles some code and deploys some war in to tomcat after compiling. There are some copying and deleting that I need to do before and after testing. How I can do this. My current pom.xml looks like follows

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>TwoDThreeDCapture</artifactId>  
  <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>TwoDThreeDCapture Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
      <tomcat.url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/html</tomcat.url>
      <tomcat.username>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/html</tomcat.username>
      <install.path>/TwoDThreeDCapture</install.path>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId> mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <!-- <systemPath>/home/tharanga/Software/json_simple-1.1.jar</systemPath> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ar.com.hjg</groupId>
        <artifactId>pngj</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <!-- <systemPath>/home/tharanga/Software/pngj-2.0.0.jar</systemPath> -->
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>TwoDThreeDCapture</finalName>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins> 
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>compile</id>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <configuration>                     
                 <target unless="maven.test.skip">
                     <copy todir=".">
                        <fileset dir="src/main/resources">
                            <include    name="*.png"/>                      
                        </fileset>
                      </copy>
                    <copy todir="src/main/webapp">
                        <fileset dir="WebContent">
                            <include    name="*.html"/>
                            <include    name="*.js"/>
                            <include    name="*.css"/>                          
                        </fileset>
                      </copy>
                      <copy todir="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/">
                        <fileset dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib">
                            <include    name="*.jar"/>                      
                        </fileset>
                      </copy>
                  </target> 
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                  <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>       
        <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>${tomcat.url}</url>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <path>${install.path}</path>
                </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.apache.maven.plugins
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-antrun-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.7,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>run</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

I want to know if I am doing the right thing but this pom fails because  required png file is not copied to the proper location. I want the coping to take place before running the tests. hope some one can help me on this.

Comment: couldn't you just change the path of the web-folder (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422746/how-to-change-default-eclipse-wtp-web-resources-dynamic-folder) and for the jars you want to copy: install them in your maven repo and add them as dependencies (if they are not publicly available)

Comment: It is not really related to the dependencies. There is png file that I need in the test phase and I need to copy that from resources folder to . at the compile time and run tests which change the png file. But I need to delete that png once the tests are completed.

Comment: maven allows you to specify the resources for tests in `src/test/resources`.  They are used only for testing.  How about using that?